# Files not appearing in SharePoint Designer, but are still usable

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, css, style-library

Just today I have run into a strange problem, in SharePoint Designer my folder "Style Library", which holds the css files for my site, is empty. When I navigate to it through "All Files" it is still there, but it has nothing inside it.

However if I open my master page and follow the css hyperlink in the code there I get to the file no problem and it even shows the correct file path to reach it. But again if I click on the "Style Library" part of the file path the folder shows no items and says its empty. I am 100% positive that the files were there yesterday as I looked into it to check a few things.

We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise edition, and the css file for the master page is not the only file inside the folder.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away, I restarted SPD to no avail, but after opening, checking out, and checking back in a few of the files it was fixed, not sure why. I would still be interested in an explanation if anyone has one

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar problem. In SP designer when I open the Style Library folder, it says there are no files in this folder. But when I go into the folder from any browser, it shows all of the files there. Why can't I see these files in SP designer?!?!?!

Comment: Can you find the files from the actual SharePoint site? If so try checking one in and out a time or two, thats what seemed to work for me