# Unable to view some files in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library

I'm using `SharePoint 2013`. I have some files stored inside a `folder` in `document library`. I could see them when I use SharePoint website, however I could not view them when I go to the same folder via `SharePoint designer`. This only happens with some files and not all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Open SharePoint Designer with Administrator previlages. It will show all files.

Comment: Doesn't help...

Comment: There is "All files" link at left side in SharePoint Designer. It will show you all files in your site.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that they are files that have no checked in version. If you upload a file but do not check it in then you can see the file in SharePoint, but no one else can. You also cannot see those files in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I checked the files that I cannot view in SharePoint designer and found out that they are checked-in. Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Edited or modified user Checked In that Files,if everything fine,

It Might be caching Issue.

Try below steps:

Step 1) Delete all the files under this folder: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

Step 2) Delete all the files under this folder: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Step 3) Delete all the 14.* and 15.* folders under: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache